# Notation for function composition of block matrices

Tags: notation

How is the notation for function composition $f$ of, for instance, a matrix composition below?

\begin{equation}
f \stackrel{?}{\circ} \left(\begin{bmatrix}
A \\
B \\
\end{bmatrix}\right) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
f(A) \\
f(B) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

I want to write an equality like following: Given two square matrices $A, \, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and trace operator $trace(A) = a^{ii}$, for Einstein's notation under force, then $trace \circ \left(\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix} trace(A) \\ trace(B) \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: If $f$ is at its base a function from the field providing the elements for $A, B$ to itself, and $f$ is then extended to a function of *all* matrices by $$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}m_{11}&\cdots&m_{1k}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\m_{l1}&\cdots&m_{lk}\end{bmatrix}\right) := \begin{bmatrix}f(m_{11})&\cdots&f(m_{1k})\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\f(m_{l1})&\cdots&f(m_{lk})\end{bmatrix}$$then your equation would be true. Otherwise, it will be false, unless you put restrictions on how the matrix can be expressed as a block matrix.

Comment: I added further details for illustration.

Comment: Your illustration does not work. The trace is only defined on square matrices. If $A,B$ are square, then $\begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}$ is not square. Also the trace of a matrix is a real number, not a matrix. It is true that $$\text{trace}\begin{pmatrix}A&C\\D&B\end{pmatrix} = \text{trace}(A) + \text{trace}(b)$$ if $A, B$ are both square (though not necessarily of the same dimensions). It doesn't matter what the matrices $C, D$ are, except for having the right dimensions to form the block matrix.

Comment: Can we extend the operator to work on block matrices in the way I say?

Comment: No. But, you can *define* a new operator. But then you will need to be clear as to how it is to operate in all situations (i.e., under which situations it is defined and what it produces for them). Trace is one the common mathematical operators that everybody knows and understands. It is okay to also call your new operator "trace", provided it is always clear when your definition applies and when the common one applies. But you need to keep in mind that what you produce is something new, and not something others should know or realize.

Comment: I will call it Tracy and take it to eat ice cream.